# How to subtract a variable from a variable in a loop

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble subtracting a variable with another variable in a do while loop. My condition as shown below is X>=Y. I'm trying to have Y subtracted from X until X is less than Y while also counting the number of times the operation is completed. I have tried a couple of different ways on how to do this, but with my limited experience I couldn't figure out how to do this.

```
//X is the number to be modified while Y is the modifier. ex 12 Mod 2 X= 12 Y= 2
var X = 12
var Y = 2 
//Div will be the result of Div. Ex 10 Div 5 | Div would be 2
var Div = 0
{    do {
         X - Y, Div++
     }
     while (
         X >= Y
    )
    WScript.Echo(X + ' ' + Div
}
```

Comment: This is not JavaScript (looks like Visual basic?), and you're mkissing the closing bracket in your `.Echo`.

Comment: Looks like Windows Scripting Host (WSH) WScript which is a relative of VBScript, which is related to Visual Basic. When you do `X - Y` (which is `10`) you are not doing anything with the result of that computation. You are not assigning the answer to either X or Y, so your comparison `X >= Y` will never change. What you want to do is assign `X = X - Y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In real JS this could be:

```js
function DivideBySubtractions( value, divisor )
  {
  let rest        = value
    , occurrences = 0
    ;
  while (rest > divisor)
    {
    rest -= divisor
    occurrences++
    }
  return { occurrences, rest }
  }

console.log( '23 / 5 ->', JSON.stringify(DivideBySubtractions( 23, 5 ) ))


// please respect Whitesmiths style coding !
```